# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'funct'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-import, drive

I'm using Google Colab and I want to import a file from the same directory.

I've mounted my Drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

And then done:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/content/drive/MyDrive/NLP/Exam')
```

However when I do

```
import funct as fu
```

It throws the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'funct'
```

Despite the fact that `funct.py` is in this directory. What could I be missing?

Comment: check current directory by: !pwd   then check is your file exists in that directory or not. use ls command

Comment: If the path is correct, there's no reason for that not to work.  You've done `print(os.listdir(sys.path[0]))`  to prove that it has what you think it has?

Comment: Tim if I run your line I get `No such file or directory: '/MyDrive/NLP/Exam'`

Comment: However if I run `ls` there is the `funct.py` file.

Comment: @zest16 from funct import *

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell from your description, but if you are in a subpackage at the time of your import (e.g., a subdirectory of your main python program), and you wish to import a module from the same directory, you must give a fully qualified package name. For example, if you have:

```
- main.py
- mycode/
|-- __init__.py
|-- mymodule.py
|-- funct.py
```

and you wish to import funct from inside mymodule.py, then you must use:

```py
import mycode.funct as funct
```

If that's not it, another possible cause is that sys.path has been modified and that the entry containing an empty string ("") has been removed.  That is the entry that tells python to search the main script's directory for packages.